# Rotate each ring of the matrix M*N anticlockwise

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, rotation

I am not able to rotate a `M*N` matrix in anticlockwise direction. My code is working properly for `3*3` matrix, but when I try for any other case it is not working assume I am doing it for `4*4` matrix then only outer elements are rotating and inner 4 elements (i.e. 6,7,10,11) are not rotating. My input is 1-16 numbers as `4*4` matrix:

```
{ {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16} }
```

```java
static void antiRotateMatrix(int m, int n, int mat[][]) {
    int row = 0, col = n - 1;
    int prev, curr;
    while (row < m && col < n) {
        if (row + 1 == m || col - 1 == 0) {
            break;
        }
        prev = mat[row + 1][col];
        for (int i = col; i >= 0; i--) {
            curr = mat[row][i];
            mat[row][i] = prev;
            prev = curr;
        }
        row++;

        for (int i = row; i < m; i++) {
            curr = mat[i][0];
            mat[i][0] = prev;
            prev = curr;
        }
        n--;

        if (row < m) {
            for (int i = n - 2; i <= col; i++) {
                curr = mat[m - 1][i];
                mat[m - 1][i] = prev;
                prev = curr;
            }
        }
        m--;
        if (col <= n) {
            for (int i = m - 1; i >= row; i--) {
                curr = mat[i][col];
                mat[i][col] = prev;
                prev = curr;
            }
        }
        col++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++)
            System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

For `4*4` I should get

```
{{2,3,4,8},{1,7,11,12},{5,6,10,16},{9,13,14,15}}
```

but I am getting

```
{{2,3,4,8},{1,6,7,12},{5,10,11,16},{9,13,14,15}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotate matrix element of each layer `M*N` in anticlockwise direction:

```py
for z in range(r):#r = n times to rotate your element of each layer
    top = 0
    bottom = len(matrix)-1

    left = 0
    right = len(matrix[0])-1

    while left < right and top < bottom: # anticlockwise rotation of each layer.
        prev = matrix[top+1][right]
        for i in range(right,left-1,-1):
            curr = matrix[top][i]
            matrix[top][i]= prev
            prev =curr
        top += 1
        for i in range(top,bottom+1):
            curr = matrix[i][left]
            matrix[i][left]=prev
            prev=curr
        left += 1
        for i in range(left,right+1):
            curr =matrix[bottom][i]
            matrix[bottom][i]=prev
            prev = curr
        bottom -=1
        for i in range(bottom,top-1,-1):
            curr = matrix[i][right]
            matrix[i][right]=prev
            prev = curr
        right -=1
```

For clockwise go to https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/rotate-matrix-elements/

I hope you can apply this `#python` code to `#java`, logic is the same. Or select python in hackerrank.