# rotate the outer ring of matrix in anticlockwise by k element and inner ring in clockwise by k element in java

Tags: java, matrix

please help me to solve the below problem in java to rotate the outer ring of matrix in anticlockwise by k element and inner ring in clockwise by k element in java and the middle element remains constant.
The sample input is
m=5,n=6,k=1 where m is no of rows,n is no of column and k is the number of required shift and the input matrix is

```
1  2  3  4  5  6
7  8  9  10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30
```

and the expected output is

```
2  3  4  5  6  12
1  14 8  9  10 18
7  20 15 16 11 24
13 21 22 23 17 30
19 25 26 27 28 29
```

But I am getting error while I tried to solve this problem by the following steps 1.converting the martix into spiralarray. 
2.perform reversal algorithm for array rotation.
3.Again convert the array into matrix form and the sample code is

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int m,n,k;
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        m=sc.nextInt();
        n=sc.nextInt();
        k=sc.nextInt(); 
        int mat[][]=new int[m][n];
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                mat[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
            }     
        }
        spiralToArray(mat,m,n,k);
    }
    static void fillSpiralPrint(int temp[],int m,int n)
    {
        int r=0;
        int c=0;
        int co=0;
        int rl=m;
        int cl=n;
        int mat[][]=new int[m][n];
        while(r<rl && c<cl)
        {
            for(int i=c;i<cl;i++)
            {
                mat[r][i]=temp[co++];  
            }
            r++;
            for(int i=r;i<rl;i++)
            {
                mat[i][cl-1]=temp[co++];
            }
            cl--;
            if(r<rl)
            {
                for(int i=cl-1;i>=c;i--)
                {
                    mat[rl-1][i]=temp[co++];
                }
                rl--;
            }
            if(c<cl)
            {
                for(int i=rl-1;i>=r;i--)
                {
                    mat[i][c]=temp[co++];
                }
                c++;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(mat[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }   
    }
    static void reverseA(int temp[],int start,int end)
    {
        int t;
        while(start<end)
        {
            t=temp[start];
            temp[start]=temp[end];
            temp[end]=t;
            start++;
            end--;
        }
    }
    /* 
    static void rotateC(int arr[],int k)
    {
        int n=arr.length;
        reverseA(arr,0,n-k-1);
        reverseA(arr,n-k,n-1);
        reverseA(arr,0,n-1);
    }
    */
    static void rotateAC(int temp[],int k)
    {
        int n=temp.length;
        reverseA(temp,0,k-1);
        reverseA(temp,k,n-1);
        reverseA(temp,0,n-1);
    }

static void spiralToArray(int mat[][],int m,int n,int k)
{
    int r=0;
    int c=0;
    int co=0;
    int rl=m;
    int cl=n;
    int start=0;
    int temp[]=new int[m*n];
    while(r<rl && c<cl)
    {
        int end=start;
        for(int i=c;i<cl;i++)
        {
            temp[co++]=mat[r][i]; 
            end++;
        }
        r++;
        for(int i=r;i<rl;i++)
        {
            temp[co++]=mat[i][cl-1];
            end++;
        }
        cl--;
        if(r<rl)
        {
            for(int i=cl-1;i>=c;i--)
            {
                temp[co++]=mat[rl-1][i];
                end++;
            }
            rl--;
        }
        if(c<cl)
        {
            for(int i=rl-1;i>=r;i--)
            {
                temp[co++]=mat[i][c];
                end++;
            }
            c++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<co;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(temp[i]+" ");
        }
        if(end-start>k)
        {
            rotateAC(temp,k);
            start=end;
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    fillSpiralPrint(temp,m,n);
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more information about the question. What have you tried? Where is the code? Which errors did you get?

Comment: as @yagizcandegirmenci pointed you need to add some sample code and describe what you have tried so far, if you are trying to make complex matrix operations you can check http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: Code examples are great. They are fantastic. But ... please format them before you post so we can at least see things like scope? And if you put any tabular data in, make sure the columns line up? Any code blocks in your question use a monospace font, so that kind of alignment is easier. I edit the question with the type of whitespace I'm describing. Only 2 things: For this question, please add sample output as well (or link to site where code may be run); explain why `rotateC` is disabled?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683000/rotate-matrix-mn-anticlockwise

Comment: I have provided an answer in [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63588356/1911064).